Issue where Node.js environment resets when VSCode is restarted
I was working with Node.js in VSCode earlier this week, and had no trouble running/writing programs with it, but when I tried to run a js file earlier today, I got the following error message:
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

node demo.js

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException





I initially installed Node through the VSCode terminal with the instructions provided here:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager?utm_cta=website-data-cloud-dummies
I was able to "fix" the problem by running the configure environment step again (fnm env --use-on-cd | Out-String | Invoke-Expression), but I have no idea why it keeps resetting every time I exit and then reopen VSCode.
Anyone know why it might be resetting, and how I can stop it from doing that?
When trying to problem solve this, I just entered the Node installation commands again one by one, while attempting to run the js file after each step. It said I already had fnm installed, so I don't think that's where the issue originated from. I also tried running the third command on that installation page (the one that actually installs Node - fnm use --install-if-missing 20), and that didn't go through another installation process, so I think it has something to do with the environment.

I've seen exactly this issue (but not on my machine) which is why I ended up here. I don't think it's related to VS Code running in restricted mode (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust) or the execution policies of Powershell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.4&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#bypass).

Deeply annoying suggestion but would you mind installing the latest version of Powershell? I tried using winget to do this but it didn't work. Downloading the MSI did (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.4#installing-the-msi-package). The installer mentioned stuff about profiles which confused me as when I attempt to access my $PROFILE, it doesn't seem to exist.
